# Elegant early exit from a spawned ffmpeg process in C

Tags: c, linux, video, ffmpeg, gtk3

I have a program where I build an ffmpeg command string to capture videos with options input through a gtk3 gui. Once I have all my options selected, I spawn a process with the ffmpeg command string. And I add a child watch to tell me when the process has completed.

```
  // Spawn child process 
  ret = g_spawn_async (NULL, argin, NULL, G_SPAWN_DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, NULL, NULL, &pid1, NULL);
  if ( !ret )
  {
    g_error ("SPAWN FAILED");
    return;
  }

/* Add watch function to catch termination of the process.  This function
   * will clean any remnants of process */
  g_child_watch_add (pid1, (GChildWatchFunc)cb_child_watch, widget );
```

Executing ffmpeg from a terminal using a command line, the program will give an option to input a "q" at the terminal to end the ffmpeg process early.
Is there any way to send a "q" to that spawned process to elegantly end the ffmpeg? I'm fairly sure I could kill the process using the process id, but I would rather stop it using a mechanism that allows ffmpeg to gracefully exit..
This is running Centos 7, kernel 4.7.5, ffmpeg version 3.0.2.
Since I can still access the terminal where the ffmpeg output is displayed, I've tried typing a "q", but it has no effect on the process.

Comment: You could send a terminate signal instead of a kill signal to the PID anyway.

Comment: you could try "q\n"

Comment: @oldtechaa  That suggestion seems to work well, make it an answer and I'll upvote. I made a halt button in gtk with a callback that makes a C call  kill(pid,SIGTERM). The videos all seem to be in good shape, which was my main concern.

Comment: @aergistal Even though I mentioned typing at the terminal, I was really looking for a solution I could incorporate into my C code. Is there a way to send the 'q/n' to my process that would just let ffmpeg end gracefully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, instead of trying to gracefully use `q`, try using `kill` and a `SIGTERM`. This would still offer your graceful shutdown, although it may not always stop ffmpeg immediately.

Comment: this answer seems to work perfectly. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to have my upvote displayed. But you have solved one of my problems. Thanks!

Comment: how to stop FFmpeg execution from code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664689/stop-cancel-execution-of-ffmpeg-command I can't kill process because my Android app is process and ffmpeg also uses this process (separate thread)