# Stop/cancel execution of FFmpeg command

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

There is FFmpeg Static (binary) available for Android and we can stop/cancel some FFmpeg execution (command) while it's doing something https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/33

But I want to use FFmpeg shared libraries and JNI, I found next library https://github.com/IljaKosynkin/FFmpeg-Development-Kit (it works ok)

But there is no option to stop execution of FFmpeg command (or killing the process)

We use Java native `run` method there to start execute some command:

Java:
https://github.com/IljaKosynkin/FFmpeg-Development-Kit/blob/master/JNI/app/src/main/java/com/example/ilja/jni/VideoKit.java#L57

and then in C we call FFmpeg's `main` method:

C:
https://github.com/IljaKosynkin/FFmpeg-Development-Kit/blob/master/JNI/app/jni/videokit.c#L41

How can I stop/cancel some FFmpeg executing after I called Java run and C main methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to edit ffmmpeg class (add some variables to check if it should execute farther or not)